# Sound doesn't work after using microsoft teams

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, google-chrome, alsa, microsoft-teams

After using Microsoft Teams today, my sound stopped working.

It was working fine before the meeting, and it worked fine during the meeting. It just stopped working after the meeting stopped.

I attended the meeting through Google Chrome (Teams doesn't work with Firefox, in my experience).

With music playing inaudibly from my media player, I checked the Sound Mixer settings, and could see that the audio was being registered by the sound system. I could see the levels. The output channel was not muted. Configuration was set to `Analogue Stereo Duplex`.

Why is it it not working?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that Microsoft Teams had left the audio configuration set to `Analogue Stereo Duplex`.

I fixed it by setting it instead to `Analogue Stereo Output`.